# Flatten XML array to a single row in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have thousands of XML files which each have an array of key/value pairs. Like this:

```xml
<extras>
  <extra>
    <key>key_name_1</key>
    <value>value_1</value>
  </extra>
  <extra>
    <key>key_name_2</key>
    <value>value_2</value>
  </extra>
</extras>
```

I need to be able to create a query that produces a single-row response for each XML file containing each of those values in a separated column named by the key. With MySQL, I was able to use extractvalue with XPath ('extras/extra[key="key_name_1"/value') for this, but with Snowflake I am not able to find a solution for this.

I have tried lateral flatten and then picking up the value from THIS array, but I haven't succeeded. It is probably something simple, but I am not able to find the solution.

## ---Update---

I could always use something like this:

```
XMLGET(XMLGET("xml_data", 'extras'):"$"[0], 'value'):"$"
```

Unfortunately, all keys aren't always available making this useless.

Can it be that I have to do a UDF for this?

## --- Update 2 ---

Got it working following way:

```sql
WITH Extra_1 AS (
    SELECT
        "id" as "id",
        XMLGET(extra.value, 'value'):"$" AS "value"
    FROM table,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(XMLGET("xml_data", 'extras'):"$") extra
    WHERE XMLGET(extra.value, 'key'):"$" = 'key_name_1'
),
WITH Extra_2 AS (
    SELECT
        "id" AS "id",
        XMLGET(extra.value, 'value'):"$" AS "value"
    FROM table,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(XMLGET("xml_data", 'extras'):"$") extra
    WHERE XMLGET(extra.value, 'key'):"$" = 'key_name_2'
)
SELECT
    "id",
    Extra_1."value" AS "key_name_1",
    Extra_2."value" AS "key_name_2",
FROM table
    JOIN Extra_1 ON Extra_1."id" = table."id";
    JOIN Extra_2 ON Extra_2."id" = table."id";
```

Hopefully, someone has a simpler way to do this.

This is how easily it can be done in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    extractvalue( xml_data,'/extras/extra[key="key_name_1"]/value') AS key_name_1,
    extractvalue( xml_data,'/extras/extra[key="key_name_2"]/value') AS key_name_2
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "large amount of columns" then FlATTEN the data then pivot it (or some other GROUP BY)

```
WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT column1 as id,
        PARSE_XML(column2) as col_xml
    FROM VALUES
        (1, '<extras><extra><key>key_name_1</key><value>value_1</value></extra>
                     <extra><key>key_name_2</key><value>value_2</value></extra>
             </extras>'),
        (2, '<extras><extra><key>key_name_1</key><value>value_3</value></extra>
             </extras>'),
        (3, '<extras><extra><key>key_name_2</key><value>value_4</value></extra>
             </extras>')
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM (
     SELECT 
        t.id
        --,f.seq
        ,xmlget(f.value,'key'):"$"::text as key
        ,xmlget(f.value,'value'):"$"::text as value
    FROM fake_data as t
      ,table(flatten(input=>to_array(t.col_xml:"$"))) f
 ) d pivot(min(value) for key in ('key_name_1','key_name_2')) as p
 ORDER BY id;
```

gives:

| ID | 'key_name_1' | 'key_name_2' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value_1 | value_2 |
| 2 | value_3 |  |
| 3 |  | value_4 |

Things to note with this solution the input to FLATTEN is forced to an array so that the XML object that have only one child are not thought of as a object, but an array, so the FLATTEN process is consistant.

Comment: Pivot was the magic function I was missing. Late thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `FLATTEN` and `XMLGET`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t
AS
SELECT 1 AS id, PARSE_XML('<extras>
  <extra>
    <key>key_name_1</key>
    <value>value_1</value>
  </extra>
  <extra>
    <key>key_name_2</key>
    <value>value_2</value>
  </extra>
</extras>') AS col_xml
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, PARSE_XML('<extras>
  <extra>
    <key>key_name_3</key>
    <value>value_3</value>
  </extra>
  <extra>
    <key>key_name_4</key>
    <value>value_4</value>
  </extra>
 <extra>
    <key>key_name_5</key>
    <value>value_5</value>
  </extra>
</extras>') AS col;
```

Query:

```
SELECT id,  
    XMLGET(s.VALUE,  'key'):"$"::STRING AS k
   ,XMLGET(s.VALUE,  'value'):"$"::STRING AS val
FROM t
,LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => t.col_xml:"$") s
WHERE GET(s.value, '@')::STRING='extra';
```

Output:

[image]

---

Single row:

```
SELECT id 
    ,GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 0), '$')[0]:"$"::STRING AS key1
    ,GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 0), '$')[1]:"$"::STRING AS value1
    ,GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 1), '$')[0]:"$"::STRING AS key2
    ,GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 1), '$')[1]:"$"::STRING AS value2
    ,GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 2), '$')[0]:"$"::STRING AS key2
    ,GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 2), '$')[1]:"$"::STRING AS value2
FROM t;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this solution gives multiple rows per file. What Is needed is to have a single row per XML file with all values in it: 1, value_1, value_2, ...

Comment: @Dkr Single row is also possible

Comment: Unfortunately, some keys are optional which makes indexing like this impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 2 values you are wanting to pull you can merge Lukasz's answer with a CASE:

```
WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT column1 as id,
        PARSE_XML(column2) as col_xml
    FROM VALUES
        (1, '<extras><extra><key>key_name_1</key><value>value_1</value></extra>
                     <extra><key>key_name_2</key><value>value_2</value></extra>
             </extras>'),
        (2, '<extras><extra><key>key_name_1</key><value>value_3</value></extra>
             </extras>'),
        (3, '<extras><extra><key>key_name_2</key><value>value_4</value></extra>
             </extras>')
 )
 SELECT *
    ,case 
        when GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 0), '$')[0]:"$" = 'key_name_1' then GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 0), '$')[1]:"$"::STRING
        when GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 1), '$')[0]:"$" = 'key_name_1' then GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 1), '$')[1]:"$"::STRING
    end as key_name_1
    ,case 
        when GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 0), '$')[0]:"$" = 'key_name_2' then GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 0), '$')[1]:"$"::STRING
        when GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 1), '$')[0]:"$" = 'key_name_2' then GET(XMLGET(t.col_xml,  'extra', 1), '$')[1]:"$"::STRING
    end as key_name_2      
FROM fake_data as t;
```

which gives:

| ID | COL_XML | KEY_NAME_1 | KEY_NAME_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | key_name_1 value_1 key_name_2 value_2 | value_1 | value_2 |
| 2 | key_name_1 value_3 | value_3 |  |
| 3 | key_name_2 value_4 |  | value_4 |

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, there are up to 15 different keys from which  I need to fetch six. So, at the moment it seems like I either need to have six CTEs or six cases with a long list of checks. The third option is to create UDF to fetch it but seems like there is no simple way to solve this problem.

Comment: you can flatten and pivot the data